Can we have duplicate key in scala Map?
I have gone through couple of blog and got to know that scala Map can not have duplicate key.
But when I tried then it works , I mean didn't throw any error.
So is it true or ?
val subjects = Map(1 -> "DS",2 -> "C++", 3 -> "Java", 1-> "DF")
println(subjects)
output : Map(1 -> DF, 2 -> C++, 3 -> Java)

It is not showing in output but ideally it should throw error while running command?

You don’t have a duplicate key in the map. It’s not invalid to overwrite existing keys.

The second time you add an existing key in the map, you are overriding the one that was first added.

As you can see the final result doesn't have any duplicated keys. When you create a collection using the varagrs syntax, you can imagine that it starts with an empty collection and starts adding each element one by one. In the case of maps, if you re-add a key, you simply overwrite the value.

Thanks @GastónSchabas It is clear now, means it will not throw error but in Final result it will override so it will not have duplicate.

In Scala, a Map is a collection of key-value pairs where each key is unique.  A Map cannot have a duplicate key because the key declaration follows the hashing technique.
If you try to declare the same key with multiple values, particularly in the scala Map case it updates the value of that particular key and won't throw any exception.
Eg:
  val map = Map(1 -> "london", 2 -> "world", 1 -> "hello")

if you print this, the output must be Map(1 -> "hello",2 -> "world")
val map = Map(1 -> "hello", 2 -> "world", 1 -> "london")

if you print this, the output must be Map(1 -> "london",2 -> "world")
